# typing keys of 2nd depth interface objects

Tags: typescript

on a 3rd party library (which i can't change) i have the following interface:

```js
interface MyInterface {
    x: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
    },
    y: {
        d: 4,
        e: 5,
        f: 6,
    },
    z: {
        g: 7,
        h: 8,
        i: 9,
    },
}
```

i want to create a type (`Values2ndDepth`) that describes **a union of all the keys of all the object in the interface**, so the following will be enforced:

```js
let key: Values2ndDepth<MyInterface>;
key = 'a'; // ok
key = 'i'; // ok
key = 'j'; // error - as doesn't exist in the above.
```

some of my tries:

```js
type Values2ndDepth<T extends object> = keyof T[keyof T];
type Values2ndDepth<T extends object> = T extends {[k: string]: (infer R)} ? keyof R : never;
type Values2ndDepth<T extends object> = T extends Record<string, infer R> ? keyof R : never;
type Values2ndDepth<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = T[K] extends object ? keyof T[K] : never;
```

Answer (score 4):

after a while - i found a solution!

```js
type Values2ndDepth<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    K extends keyof T ? T[K] extends object ? keyof T[K] : never : never;
```

- making sure `K` describes `T`'s keys
- making sure the value of `T[K]` is another object
- taking `T[K]`'s keys

any other solutions? maybe something more elegant?

Comment: Here's an alternative approach using mapped types, but I wouldn't say it's more elegant.  Yours is better, in my opinion. `type ValueKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? keyof T[K] : never; }` defines an object with the original keys whose values are the keys are that value.  Then `type Values2ndDepth<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = ValueKeys<T>[K]` can access individual or all properties of that type.